# Where should I resctric the ocurrences of a type in an XML Schema, element or sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there any difference between limiting the occurrences of an element in the `element` tag or the `sequence` tag, what would be the best place to do it? Or it's just a matter of style?

Example:

```
<xs:element name="Provider">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOcurrs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Distribuitor"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

or

```
<xs:element name="Provider">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Distribuitor"  minOcurrs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to put it on the element instead because the sequence specifies the order in which the elements must appear.  I believe if you put it on the elements themselves, you are being more clear on what you want.  I don't think in your case it makes a difference with 1 element, but imagine if you had 10 elements for example and each element could have a different number of minOcurrs and maxOccurs, you probably would want to specify it on each element then instead of at the sequence level.